# Bash command not found comparing string with variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to compare a variable with a string (how hard can it be)

```
#!/bin/bash

a=22

if ["$a" == "23"]
then
    echo yes yes
fi
```

I get

```
./x: line 5: [22: command not found
```

I've tried to remove quotes, or use `[[...]]`. But whatever I do, I get the `command not found` error. Any suggestions what I do wrong?

Comment: Well, that changes the error @Fabio. Now I get: `./x: line 3: local: can only be used in a function
./x: line 5: [: missing `]'`

Comment: Spaces are important delimiters in shell syntax, and adding or removing them will often change the meaning of a command.

Comment: notice that while the fundamental problem was the spacing, you should use `-eq` to compare integers instead of `==`. Furthermore, `==` is understood by Bash, but isn't POSIX compliant; use `=` instead for improved portability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ "$a" == "22" ]`  <--- you need a space before the closing backet